# How can I create a self controlled TextFormField?

Tags: flutter

I created a RoundTextInput, which is basically a custom widget in which I expose the parameters that I want to change and set others to be constant.

As my project got bigger I found the necessity to clear some inputs dinamically on the press of a button, and for that I used some Controllers.

The problem is that if I have many inputs, i'll also need many controllers, which make the screen file way too 'dirty' with all the new variables.

So, what I tried to do is create a self controlled input. Just declare the controller inside the widget and access it from there. But the problem lies in how can I access it there?

Shoul I create functions that call the methods of the controller? But aren't the properties of a widget class immutable? How would I change it's attributes?

Is there any way that I can make a self controlled input or should I really just make the controllers in each screen for every input that needs to be controlled and accept that this is the only way?

Comment: you can use ```reactive_forms: ^16.0.2``` https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms. which is quite easy to use and can be validated properly